# Sleep function will not work in sequence

Tags: vba

I wrote a VBA excel program some years ago with a moving graphic using sleep as below:

```
For i = 1 To (H - V) 'move in horizontal plane
With Selection
.Left = .Left - 3
End With
Sleep 10
Next i
```

I called the sleep function from kernal32 with a line of code above the module top line. All worked well

I upgraded to a 64 bit machine - all stopped working. I added the phrase "PtrSafe" to the sleep call, however all the movements now occur in one big jump.The program executes sleep first and then everything else without pausing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: include the declaration code for Sleep

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264421.aspx

```
#If Vba7 Then 
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else 
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#EndIf
```

The value is in Milliseconds, so you can use `Sleep 10000` instead